# "An unhandled security exception has occurred" in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, windows, caching, iis

We are getting the following error on our web server. We are also observing a strange problem leading to a virtual shuttpown to our asp.net web application. It does not crash. It simply stops processing requests. this happen regardless of the load of the server. It happens periodically, sometime every 90 minutes or 2 hours. Sometime also when no one is logged on.

We are caching certain data in memory to minimize database round trips . Could this happen when the cache expires and need to be reloaded due to something not configured properly?

```
Event code: 4010 
Event message: An unhandled security exception has occurred. 
Event time: 21/05/2014 08:57:36 
Event time (UTC): 21/05/2014 06:57:36 
Event ID: 9106022293a944059cd7a35dbdc48024 
Event sequence: 262 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/3/ROOT-1-130451258156698671 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: D:\FolderXXX\ 
    Machine name: MachineXXXX 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 6664 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: UserXXX 

Request information: 
    Request URL:  
    Request path:  
    User host address:  
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: UserXXX
```

Custom event details:

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it could happen when the cache expires and needs to be reloaded again and the account has no rights. Either check how you reload cache and if account has rights or enable tracing for more information.

Read about similar issue at http://forums.asp.net/t/1629856.aspx

[How to: Enable Tracing for an ASP.NET Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0x5wc973%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Could you elaborate on "Either check how you reload cache and if account has rights"? The user running the application pool does have the right to load the data in the first place otherwise would it be allowed to load it?

Comment: the page "How to: Enable Tracing for an ASP.NET Application" says when you are using "classic" mode. I'm using "integrated mode"

Comment: Without seeing the code itself, I could suggest following: 1) try to obtain more information on the exception. e.g. see http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis 2) exception says "User: Is authenticated: False" - so it must be something with a code that has to do with permissions. It might be not database (because you said the user has permissions) but anything else 3) you could try to disable a cache or disable its reload and see if the exception will go - currently we are not sure that it is due to the cache.

Comment: Thanks again. The url with help to trouble shooting looks good and i will look into this. Regarding the "User: Is authenticated: false" i should add that most of the site requires authentication. Could this be a search engine trying to access some page that require authentication? Also i must say that i log every error in the application to a file by handling the "on error" event in global.asax.  This particular error is not logged.  I will follow the instructions on the trouble shooting page and report back on any eventual finding. Disabling the cache will only be attempted in the end.

Comment: You could also consider ELMAH for logging errors https://code.google.com/p/elmah/

Comment: ELMMAH looks very impressive. In the context of the "unhandled security exception", what kind of extra information could i get from such a logging system?

Comment: You need a call stack when the exception was thrown (a stack trace that can be used to determine where the error occurs in the code - all the called methods and the line numbers in the source file where the calls are made)